# tf.trainable_variables() returns a blank list

Tags: tensorflow

Here is part of my code:

```
class agent():
    def __init__(self, lr, s_size,a_size,h_size):

    self.lr = lr
    self.s_size = s_size
    self.a_size = a_size
    self.h_size = h_size
    self.grad_clip = 1.0
    self.global_step = tf.Variable(0, name='global_step', trainable=False)

    with tf.variable_scope('agent', reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        self.g3 = tf.Graph()
        with self.g3.as_default():

            self.build_model() ## building network 
            init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            self.saver = tf.train.Saver()
    self.sess = tf.Session(graph = self.g3)
    self.sess.run(self.init)  ## initialize the variables
```

outside this class, I called

```
    gradBuffer = agent.sess.run(tf.trainable_variables('agent'))
```

`gradBuffer` is always a blank list. I found related solutions online including set "`reuse == True`" and set the scope name. I did all, but it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution, but there may be other optimal solutions outside my knowledge. Answer here for a record.

`tvars = tf.trainable_variables('agent')` should be defined under the designated graph and fetch the values later once needed. The key is to call trainable variables under the graph.

This is my understanding, if somewhere is wrong, please let me know. Thanks!